# Error web services

Tags: html5, sap, abap

hay unos servicios web que proporcionan contenido HTML a una página. 
La página puede utilizar los servicios web, o bien utilizar los archivos del servidor con el código fuente de los servicios web en formato de texto.

Cuando la página utiliza los servicios web funciona correctamente, pero si me descargo el código fuente de los servicios web haciendo Ctrl. + U en el navegador, subo los archivos al servidor en formato .TXT y utilizo los archivos la página no funciona.

Hay versiones viejas del código fuente en el servidor en .TXT, me dicen que siempre se guardó el código fuente del servicio web de esta manera y no daba problemas.

Yo pienso que tiene que ver con la codificación de caracteres pero el archivo funciona en remoto y no cuando lo guardo en TXT y lo almaceno en el servidor, entiendo que el contenido es el mismo y por tanto la codificación de caracteres también ¿no?

El SAP lanza una excepción del tipo: CX_SY_CONVERSION_CODEPAGE.

Si a alguien se le ocurre qué puede estar ocasionando el problema se lo agradezco.

(siento no subir ejemplo de código pero imagino que no puedo hacerlo por razones de protección de datos ya que se trata de una empresa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que el notepad tradicional convierte el formato de los TXT y tenían que estar en un formato determinado. Utilicé el Notepad++, puse el formato que me interesaba y listo.